# Reusing a render target "spills paint"?

Tags: xna, render-to-texture

I have some code that goes like this:

```
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, myRenderTarget);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend, SpriteSortMode.Immediate, SaveStateMode.None);
        myEffect.Begin();
        myEffectCurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(aRegularTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        myEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].End();
        myEffect.End();
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, backBuffer);
        Texture2D bloomTexture = myRenderTarget.GetTexture();
        ...
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, myRenderTarget);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(aRegularTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, backBuffer);
        aRegularTexture = myRenderTarget.GetTexture(); 
        //SHOULD be doing nothing, since I'm just rendering said texture into a render target and pulling it back out
```

(note: this is trimmed down to the minimal reproduction code, not quite what i actually use)

If I render aRegularTexture to the screen before the second block of code, it looks fine and untouched. But if I render it out after the second block of code, it's set to the contents of aModifiedTexture, even though I'm never doing anything that would result in that. Why? (Using XNA 3.1)

Answer (score 1):

Via Shawn Hargreaves: "GetTexture returns an alias for the same surface memory as the rendertarget itself, rather than a separate copy of the data"

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference; aRegularTexture isn't touched till i re-use that render target to do what should be a no-op. If anything, aModifiedTexture should be the same as aRegularTexture, not the other way around...

Comment: "aModifiedTexture" never actually appears in your posted code, so it's hard to know exactly what you're referring to.  Do you mean bloomTexture?

Comment: Also, if my assumptions are correct, the second code block is not a no-op.  You're taking what is (I assume) a texture that you've loaded from some resource and changing it to be an alias for the render target.